# Adding border to image

Tags: html, css

Please see my this fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/jWKdK/

And help me to add border to the image.

Regards

Comment: Use #header img instead of #header .img

Comment: Thanks Chuck..Minor mistake..Actually, I am on learning stage !!

Comment: Yes, learning on your own mistakes is better :)

Comment: For all down voters...this might not be one of YOUR LEVEL questions, but it helped me a lot. so #KEEPDOWNVOTING #StayStrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be dot before img -

```
#header img {
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#ff0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jWKdK/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this : [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v413hav/jWKdK/1/)

CSS

```
#header img {
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#ff0;
}
```

Using `.img` means you are targeting `.img` where parent is `#header` but there is no such class as `.img` so select the attribute instead

Or if you want to use `.img` than give `.img` class to your img tag : [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v413hav/jWKdK/5/)

Comment: "parent" as in ancestor, not necessarily immediate parent :)

Comment: @jensgram yup but certainly img parent over here is #header

Comment: True, but OP is learning so we might as well be specific.

Comment: @jensgram so that's why I also provided another specific option in another fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/v413hav/jWKdK/5/

Answer (score 1):

In your style remove dot from `.img`

Change `#header .img {` to `#header img {`

Answer (score 1):

That is not `.img` it should be `#header img`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jWKdK/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
#header img {
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#ff0;
}
```

Use #header img because img is tag selector not a class
You can use reference of selectors on this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp